# Terraform Plan deleting AKS Node Pool

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

Terraform plan always forces AKS cluster to be recreated if we increase  worker node in node pool

Trying Creating AKS Cluster with 1 worker node, via Terraform, it went well , Cluster is Up and running.

[image]

Post that, i tried to add one more worker node in my AKS, Terraform Show Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 2 to destroy.

[image]

Not Sure how can we increase worker node in aks node pool, if it delate the existing node pool.

```
  default_node_pool {
    name                  = var.nodepool_name
    vm_size               = var.instance_type
    orchestrator_version  = data.azurerm_kubernetes_service_versions.current.latest_version
    availability_zones    = var.zones
    enable_auto_scaling   = var.node_autoscalling
    node_count            = var.instance_count
    enable_node_public_ip = var.publicip
    vnet_subnet_id        = data.azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
    node_labels = {
      "node_pool_type"         = var.tags[0].node_pool_type
      "environment"            = var.tags[0].environment
      "nodepool_os"            = var.tags[0].nodepool_os
      "application"            = var.tags[0].application
      "manged_by"              = var.tags[0].manged_by
 }
}
```

Error

```
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
-/+ destroy and then create replacement

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster must be replaced
-/+ resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks_cluster" {
```

Thanks
Satyam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***I tested the same in my environment by creating a cluster with 2 node counts and then changed it to 3 using something like below :***

[image]

If you are using `HTTP_proxy` then it will ***by default force a replacement on that block*** and that's the reason the whole cluster will get replaced with the new configurations.

[image]

So, for a solution you can use lifecycle block in your code as I have done below:

```
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [http_proxy_config]
  }
```

***The code will be :***

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks_cluster" {
  name                       = "${var.global-prefix}-${var.cluster-id}-${var.envid}-azwe-aks-01"
  location                   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  dns_prefix                 = "${var.global-prefix}-${var.cluster-id}-${var.envid}-azwe-aks-01"
  kubernetes_version         = var.cluster-version
  private_cluster_enabled    = var.private_cluster



  default_node_pool {
    name                  = var.nodepool_name
    vm_size               = var.instance_type
    orchestrator_version  = data.azurerm_kubernetes_service_versions.current.latest_version
    availability_zones    = var.zones
    enable_auto_scaling   = var.node_autoscalling
    node_count            = var.instance_count
    enable_node_public_ip = var.publicip
    vnet_subnet_id        = azurerm_subnet.example.id  
  }


# RBAC and Azure AD Integration Block
  role_based_access_control {
    enabled = true
} 

  http_proxy_config {
    http_proxy       = "http://xxxx"
    https_proxy      = "http://xxxx"
    no_proxy         = ["localhost","xxx","xxxx"]
  }
# Identity (System Assigned or Service Principal)
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
}

# Add On Profiles
  addon_profile {
    azure_policy {enabled =  true}
  }
# Network Profile
  network_profile {
    network_plugin = "azure"
    network_policy = "calico"
  }
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [http_proxy_config]
  }
}
```

Comment: It resolves the Issue but the whole is now Proxied, I mean all the pods on the cluster are inheriting proxy which is risk.